# How To Get A Value Of a Promise Outside a Promise In NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I try to access the data that is inside a promise from outside the promise.

If I use the code below for `console.log(result)`, the data appears.

```
dataModel.lastIndex(name, function(err, result){ console.log(result) });
```

But, when I try to use return and a variable to save the return results, I can't find the results.

```
let data1 = dataModel.lastIndex(name, function(err, result){ return result});

console.log(data1);  // doesn't work
```

How do I return the results that have been promised so that I can use them outside of promise?

Because I have tried to find some of the same questions, but have not been able to solve my problem.

I beg for help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sir,please read about callbacks becuase nodejs is async programming and hence you won't get anything in your code

Comment: I mean, in promise, I can get data using console.log(callback') or whatever variabel I'm use. So, how can I do so that I can display the data inside the promise "with a variable that is outside of the promise?" but, thank you for your response, sir.

Comment: You can't.  First off, there are no promises shown in your code at all.  You just show a plain async callback.  Second, asynchronous callbacks occur long AFTER your function has already returned so you CANNOT return their value, ever.  Instead, you use the value inside the callback.